# URL Redirection in import.io

Tags: import.io

Hi I am working on URL http://www.goodtoknow.co.uk/recipes/healthy?page=1&cost_range=any&total_time=any&skill_level=any&tags%5B0%5D=Healthy&tags%5B1%5D=Healthy and creating extractor. But the URL gets redirected to the URL http://www.goodtoknow.co.uk/recipes/healthy automatically in import.io I want to create extractor for the first mentioned URL. Is it possible? Is it happening because of the page requires cookies which they does not support?

Answer (score 2):

If you examine the network requests using chrome or any other web-debugger you can see that the website is calling a second URL for the recipie data:

```
http://www.goodtoknow.co.uk/recipes/search?q=&page=1&cost_range=any&total_time=any&skill_level=any&tags[0]=Healthy&tags[1]=Healthy&_=1458727079183
```

This url does not redirect without cookies and you can set the page number manually.

Try training using this URL and see if it avoids the redirecting.